# Run MYSQL trigger without updating table

Tags: php, mysql

I've just found out about triggers and I'd like to know if this is possible to do somehow. For example, in the site I'm making, one table of IP addresses has `LastActivity` updated on page load, but that's it.

Could I write this as a trigger and maybe do something like `UPDATE (iptable) WHERE Address = (ipaddress)`, so that while it technically won't update anything, it'll run the trigger on the matching row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers triggered when you perform type of operation that you bind trigger with. 
If you bind your trigger to update, it will be executed with no depends on what data you try to update.
But you should read about update [statements](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) and [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

For your needs you can use this one:

```
UPDATE iptable SET Address = Address WHERE Address = ipaddress;
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up coming to the same idea so I'll mark this as best answer. This wasn't info in the question, but I just remembered there's one table that gets a new row each page load, so I should be able to trigger that :)

Comment: This is an amazing solution to run triggers on historical data!   We've recently created triggers to sync inserted or updated data elsewhere, and used this trick to sync the existing/historical data!   I wish I could give this more points than a simple upvote. 

Answer (score 1):

In short: no. When you say "updated on page load" the "page" is served by an application server (guessing php as per your tag?). The page is not served directly from the database. So, your application server needs to tell mysql to update iptable through a query.